# how to implement night mode book reader in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, core-image

I tried to invert colors for an image to simulate **night mode** in a pdf reader I am working on, so I tried to use one's complement. I have an issue that the image gets moved to the right also there is some noise.

So I am asking if there a better way, Please show me. Also if there is a pdf reader library with night mode implemented, You can tell me about it and save the day for me.

**Note:**

1- I used code from this link: http://five.agency/iphone-image-processing/

2- The book is pdf and the pages are as images not text.

3- I am attaching the test image and the result.

```
self.imageView.image = [self onesComplement:image];
```

....

```
-(UIImage *)onesComplement:(UIImage *) image
{

CGImageRef sourceImage = image.CGImage;
CFDataRef theData;
theData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(sourceImage));
UInt8 *pixelData = (UInt8 *) CFDataGetBytePtr(theData);
long dataLength = CFDataGetLength(theData);
int red = 0;
int green = 1;
int blue = 2;
for (int index = 0; index < dataLength; index +=4) {
    pixelData[index + green] = ~ pixelData[index + green];
        pixelData[index + red] = ~ pixelData[index + red];
        pixelData[index + blue] = ~ pixelData[index + blue];

}
short bitsPerComponent = 8;
CGContextRef context;
context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixelData,
                                CGImageGetWidth(sourceImage),
                                CGImageGetHeight(sourceImage),
                                bitsPerComponent,
                                CGImageGetBytesPerRow(sourceImage),
                                CGImageGetColorSpace(sourceImage),
                                kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);

CGImageRef newCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newCGImage];
CGContextRelease(context);
CFRelease(theData);
CGImageRelease(newCGImage);
return  newImage;
}
```

[image: Test image]

[image: Result image]

Comment: I had to use a closed source library to view pdfs that implements night mode

Answer (score -2):

Create a night mode toggle, once it's turned on, add a UILabel above the book page image and give it a black background with low alpha in a way that you will see the book through it and the screen will be dark enough for night mode reading.

Comment: I see in night mode in reading apps the text color gets white and the background gets black. That is why I thought in inverting colors.

Comment: If you were talking about simple uitextview then it would have been easy to do, however, since you are showing an image, you don't have many options... The apps you are talking about must not be using images to show the book as you do.